# Nemo doesn't ask confirmation on delete

Tags: linux-mint, nemo

I use Linux Mint 17.1 which uses nemo as filemanager.

If I select a file and press <kbd>del</kbd> it moves the file into Trash without confirmation although in settings I selected to ask for confirmation.

How can I correct this behaviour?

Comment: Did you take a look at: Nemo | Edit | Preferences | Behavior | Trash options?  Also did you re-install Nemo.  This fixed issues for me.

Answer (score 1):

This feature does not yet exist for Nemo. Please make a comment to bump this feature request up in priority, here: https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/issues/1135.